# How do I define an onChange handler for React-Select in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-select

I can't get the onchange function typing correct.  I created a handler function but typescript keeps complaining about type mismatch.

My function:

```
private handleChange(options: Array<{label: string, value: number}>) {
}
```

Typescript error:

`src/questionnaire-elements/AssessmentFactorSearch.tsx (43,9): Type '{ ref: "select"; name: string; backspaceToRemoveMessage: ""; value: { label: string; value: IAsse...' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Async<OptionValues>> & Readonly<{ children?: React...'.
  Type '{ ref: "select"; name: string; backspaceToRemoveMessage: ""; value: { label: string; value: IAsse...' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<ReactAsyncSelectProps<OptionValues>>'.
    Types of property 'onChange' are incompatible.
      Type '(options: { label: string; value: number; }[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'OnChangeHandler<OptionValues, Option<OptionValues> | Option<OptionValues>[]> | undefined'.
        Type '(options: { label: string; value: number; }[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'OnChangeHandler<OptionValues, Option<OptionValues> | Option<OptionValues>[]>'. (2322)`

How do I type the onchange method?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @mukama see my proposal down under. I'm not a fan of the api by react-select, but that solution would offer proper type checks.

Answer (score 13):

Based on https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2902, just write your handler like this:

```
// define your option type
type MyOption = {label: string, value: number}

// ...

  // define your onChange handler:
  private handleChange = (selected?: MyOption | MyOption[] | null) => {
    /** Code **/
  }
```

Take note of the part `MyOption | MyOption[] | null`, which matches the same structure as the definition of `onChange` in the react-select library. Just make your own `MyOption` type.

Another example in that issue thread also shows that you can pass the function inline, and in that case the type of the handler parameter is inferred automatically:

```
<Select
  onChange={selectedOption /* type is automatically inferred here */ => {
    if (Array.isArray(selectedOption)) {
      throw new Error("Unexpected type passed to ReactSelect onChange handler");
    }

    doSomethingWithSelectedValue(selectedOption.value);
  }}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2902#issuecomment-481194330 works.

Comment: no longer works: Cannot find module 'react-select/lib/types' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: Then you should look at this answer most probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/63133900/457066

Answer (score 13):

as for react-select **ˆ3.1.0** the code below should work:

```
import {ValueType, ActionMeta} from 'react-select';

type MyOptionType = { label: string, value: number }

type OnChange = (value: ValueType<MyOptionType>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<MyOptionType>) => void;
```

Comment: ValueType is a generic and requires second type.

Comment: `value: ValueType<MyOptionType , false>`.     you need to add false or true as a second parameter depending if you allow the select multiple options or not

Comment: Typescript mess. Yet have to see the added value of this.

Comment: I'm getting `Module '"react-select"' has no exported member 'ValueType'.`

Answer (score 4):

2022, using `"react-select": "^5.4.0"` and `"typescript": "4.7.4"`.

This worked for me, as per the [react-select documentation](https://react-select.com/typescript#onchange):

```js
type SelectOptionType = { label: string, value: string }

const [myState, setMyState] = useState({})

const handleSelectionChange = (option: SelectOptionType | null) => {
  if (option) {
    setMyState(option)
  }
};

...

<Select 
  options={options} 
  onChange={handleSelectionChange}
/>
```

In case you're using a multi-select, you must change the `handleSelectionChange` method signature to receive an `option` variable as a readonly array of `SelectOptionType` (as I named my option's type). Something like:

```
const handleSelectionChange = (option: readonly Option[]) => {
 // typecheck and do whatever you want e.g. setState
}
```

I'm not using the `actionMeta` which is optional, but you could receive it in your `handleSelectionChange` method as a second parameter as well.

Comment: how do you do this conditionally based on if the multi is passed in as a prop or not?

Comment: @RedBaron did you figure it out? I'm struggling to change the type based on the isMulti prop.

Answer (score 3):

Create a type for the option value:

```
type SelectValue = {
  label: string;
  value: string;
};
```

Use `MultiValue<SelectValue>` for multiple value select input. `SingleValue<SelectValue>` for single value select input.
`ActionMeta` holds info about the action performed. E.g. in multi value select input it holds the info about what is added or removed from selection.

```
import Select, { ActionMeta, MultiValue } from "react-select";

const handleSelectionChange = (
   newSelections: MultiValue<SelectValue>,
   actionMeta: ActionMeta<SelectValue>
) => {
    // define your logic
};
```

React Select version: 5.2.2

Comment: how do you do this conditionally based on if the multi is passed in as a prop or not?

Answer (score 2):

2021 answer:

1. Don't use the @types/react-select lib, it's been deprecated
2. onChange handler

Handler:

```
const addTagHandler = (tags: OnChangeValue<TagOptionType, true>) => {
    if (tags) {
      setTags((tags as TagOptionType[]).map((tag: TagOptionType) => tag.value));
    }
  };
```

Where:

1. boolean true refers to isMulti (are there multiple elements, or single)
2. Where TagOptionType looks

As follows:

```
type TagOptionType = { label: string, value: string }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second type parameter dictates if the `Select` should be typed as a multi-choice select or single.

Use `Select<MyOption, true>` for multi choice, `Select<MyOption>` for single choice.

Answer (score 0):

If people are still having a hard time, this is what worked for me (excluding the meta):

```
import { ValueType } from 'react-select/src/types';
interface MyOptionType = { value: string; label: string };

const handleChange = (value: ValueType<MyOptionType>) => {
  const val: MyOptionType = value as MyOptionType; // casting
  
  // insert your logic here using the casted variable
  ...
}
```

Comment: Where does ValueType come from in this example?

Comment: @decodedcreative thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to add that it came from `react-select` library. I have updated the code showing how it got imported.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers sadly didn't work for me. Through reading the error message I came to this solution. Please note this works only for single-select

```
import { SingleValue } from "react-select";

type OptionType = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};

// alternative: onChange(option: OptionType | null | "")
function onChange(option: SingleValue<OptionType> | "") {
  if (option === null || option === "") {
    return;
  }
  // logic
}

<Select
  ...
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the **latest version(5.8.0)** this is how you type the onChange function.

```
const handleChange = (option: OnChangeValue<SelectOptions,false>,actionMeta: ActionMeta<SelectOptions>) => {
   //...
}
```

false  --> Single Value

true --> Multi Value

where **SelectOptions** is the type of Options you pass the React Select

Answer (score -1):

None of the above worked for me. This did.

```
type SelectOption = {
  label: string
  value: string
}

const isSelectOption = (v: any): v is SelectOption => {
  if((v as SelectOption).value !== undefined) return v.value
  return false
}

<Select
  ...
  onChange={(v) => {
    if(isSelectOption(v)) {
      doSomethingWith(v.value)
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: It worked for you because you used `any` as type, so of course it worked. But the point of TypeScript is to use types, not `any`.